# Create new object for required Mode Module in every test

Tags: javascript, node.js

Since Node.js creates a global singleton for a required module, how can I create unique instances of my game below in each test?  I want to make sure that every time I start the game it's being started from a new game object that's initialing the started to false.

right now game.start, game is the same singleton used in each test, and I don't want that, I shouldn't be sharing that singleton through every test, that's bad obviously.

```
let chai = require('chai'),
    should = chai.should(),
    game = require('../src/game');

describe('Starting the Game', () => {

    it('should be able to start the game', () => {
        game.start();

        game.started.should.be.true;
    });

    it('should contain a new board to play on when game starts', () => {
        game.start();

        game.started.should.be.true;
        should.exist(game.board);
    });
});
```

**game.js**

```
var board = require('./board'),
    player = require('./player');

var game = module.exports = {
    start: start,
    started: false,
    board: board.create()
};

function start(){
    game.started = true;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to instantiate a new instance in each test, then you need to define `game` and `board` as a class.

You can then instantiate new instance of game in `beforeEach` method which gets executed before each test case.

**Game.js**

```
var Board = require('./board'),
    Player = require('./player');

class Game {
    constructor() {
        this.started = false;
        this.board = new Board();
    }
    start() {
        this.started = true;
    }
}

export default Game;
```

**game-unit-test.js**

```
const chai = require('chai'),
    should = chai.should(),
    Game = require('../../test');

let game;

describe.only('Starting the Game', () => {
    beforeEach((done) => {
        game = new Game();
        done();
    });

    it('should be able to start the game', () => {
        game.start();

        game.started.should.be.true;
    });

    it('should contain a new board to play on when game starts', () => {
        game.start();

        game.started.should.be.true;
        should.exist(game.board);
    });
});
```

Comment: what I was doing before was to clone it by doing this:  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(game));  where game is the required module.  That worked for me but yea looking for alternatives and anyone to tell me if that was safe or normal to do in my case.

Comment: yea so you're basically changing this to no longer use a node module but the new ES6 classes with export?

Comment: interesting I haven't had to add done() and my tests run green and fail when they should also.

Comment: Also, one last question, ...so lets say we did not use ES6 syntax for this.  And lets say it was still a node module with the syntax I had.  Then would my clone be reasonable or the only way to get that working with my existing syntax?  I wonder how people created instances before they started using ES6 classes, like I did with stringify?

Comment: I see you also changed to const in the test for requires.  Why not make the const a let and why not let or var but const?  Just wanted to understand.

Comment: ah, that's right, the class in my original example is the function assigned to the module.exports since a function is an object (class for analogy)

Comment: I have used `const` and not `let/var` as we are just assigning values to the variable once. Using `let/var` instead of `const` won't affect the functionality. You can imitate class in ES5 using function and then creating an object using `new` keyword. Like ```function Apple (type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.color = "red";
    this.getInfo = getAppleInfo;
}
 
var apple = new Apple('macintosh');``` Please accept the answer if it helped you in solving the problem.